# Is it possible to run console app on database change/update?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a database `A` which is connected to my website(ASP.NET MVC). Whenever there is a change/update in database `A` through the website, I want to run a console app to grab updated data from database `A` and pull it down to database `B`.

Is this possible to implement this function using `SqlDependency` or `Service Broker`, or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: You can have a simple windows service which would periodically run this console app, and Console app would have the logic to sync database A changes with database B.

Comment: Is `database b` supposed to be a direct copy of `database a`?  Why not use replication and nix the console app all together?

Comment: @Tom no. database A and B are separate databases.And database B only need a few data in database A.

Comment: There are all sorts of things built into SQL Server that can help you with this. You may want to look into [mirroring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms189852.aspx), or [log shipping](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/sql-performance/readable-secondaries-on-a-budget), or maybe even [replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms151198.aspx). Although  I recommend the first two if they will fit your needs.

Comment: @Kurubaran that can be one solution but i prefer get noticed whenever there is a change instead of periodically check for the changes.

Comment: @Zane, from the link you posted RE: Mirroring, *This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature*

Comment: Trigger and a linked server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is number of ways how you can do that. To name a few:

- setup database mirroring
- backup/restore whole db (can easily be overkill)
- use custom scripts to update one db to another
- use sync framework from ado.net
- use some custom code to update second db

While you can setup first three to be completely on database level, 4,5 (and 3 as well) uses some application.

In order to call your code on time you can use both push and pull approaches, so either setup a timer or use SqlDependency to have a callback when update happened.

On database level you can setup trigger or have a recurring job setup.

Comment: so i can use `SqlDependency` to run window application?

Comment: option 5 seems the one I need.

Comment: You can have .net app with SqlDependency set up, and execute code on `OnDependencyChange`.

Answer (score 2):

You may implement SQL SERVER CLR integration in following ways:

1. Enable CLR with SQL server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131048(SQL.100).aspx
2. Write CLR trigger : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131093(v=sql.100).aspx
3. For more info :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**UPDATE:**

You may create a sp like bellow and call this sp in a trigger for that table: [CREDIT](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2014/replace-xpcmdshell-command-line-use-with-sql-server-agent/) :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_ExecCmdShellProcess 
AS  
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @job NVARCHAR(100) ; 
        SET @job = 'xp_cmdshell replacement - ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 121) ;  

        EXEC msdb..sp_add_job @job_name = @job, 
            @description = 'Automated job to execute command shell script', 
            @owner_login_name = 'sa', @delete_level = 1 ;  

        EXEC msdb..sp_add_jobstep @job_name = @job, @step_id = 1, 
            @step_name = 'Command Shell Execution', @subsystem = 'CMDEXEC', 
            @command = 'c:\Testconsole.exe', @on_success_action = 1 ;  

        EXEC msdb..sp_add_jobserver @job_name = @job ;  

        EXEC msdb..sp_start_job @job_name = @job ;  

    END ; 
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

and I can't say better ,but I think you can go for a trigger and call a clr function in the SQL server a https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k.aspx.